# Execute command and stream results

Tags: elixir

I want to execute a system command (git clone) and stream the output to the user through a channel in Phoenix?

Can I somehow make System.cmd stream the results instead of waiting until it's done?

Or, can I write the output to a file and stream the content from there, as it's being appended?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to override output with:

```
System.cmd "git", ["clone", "YOUR_GIT"], into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line)
```

Result:

> Cloning into 'YOUR_GIT'... remote: Counting objects: 1665, done.
>                                        remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/979)  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (979/979), done.
>                                                     Receiving objects:   0% (1/166remote: Total 1665 (delta 855), reused 1331 (delta 597)
>                                                          Receiving objects:  92% (Receiving objects: 100% (1665/1665), 5.25 MiB | 376.00
>   KiB/s, done.
>                                                                      Resolving delResolving deltas: 100% (855/855), done.
>                                          Checking connectivity... done.
>   {%IO.Stream{device: :standard_io, line_or_bytes: :line, raw: false}, 0}

[docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/System.html#cmd/3)

#### Edit:

To help you achieve your specific task, redirecting the local standard stream into external one, there's a library [porcelain](https://github.com/alco/porcelain), which [handles it perfectly](https://github.com/alco/porcelain#messages).

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. System.cmd still seems to wait until it's done. This is what I ran: https://gist.github.com/Linuus/1a5ca235650cc2ba0b9a

Comment: I mean, IO.stream(:stdio, :line) just prints it to the apps standard out. Right?

Comment: sobolevn: I don't really understand. Can you show me a full example together with System.cmd?

Comment: sobolevn: It doesn't seem to work: Try this     System.cmd("git", ["clone", "--progress", git_uri, "docker-test"], stderr_to_stdout: true, into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line))
    |> Stream.map(fn(line) -> IO.inspect("FOO") end)
The IO.inspect("FOO") is never called. Everything is just printed to Standard out. I want to capture each line as a stream and send it in Phoenix channel to the client.

Answer (score 3):

I would advice on using Porcelain for this. Specifically check https://github.com/alco/porcelain#messages.

You can use `Porcelain.spawn_shell` to run your command with the `out: {:send, self()}` option and implement matching `handle_info` callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Porcelain, which has a go executable dependency, you can use port, like so:

```
  def long do
    port = Port.open({:spawn_executable, /path/to/command"}, [:stderr_to_stdout, :binary, :exit_status, args: ["arg1"]])
    stream_output(port)
  end

  defp stream_output(port) do
    receive do
      {^port, {:data, data}} ->
        Logger.info(data) # send to phoenix channel
        stream_output(port)
      {^port, {:exit_status, 0}} ->
        Logger.info("Command success")
      {^port, {:exit_status, status}} ->
        Logger.info("Command error, status #{status}")
    end
  end
```